# Unable to Connect with FIX Protoocol using quickfix

Tags: python-3.x, api, ssl, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm trying to use the [Gain Futures API](https://gainfutures.com/GFAPI/) via the FIX protocol. I'm using quickfix (and a 3rd party library, called [transfixed](https://github.com/th3sys/transfixed)) to establish the connection. The Gain Futures API allows you to connect (in the test environment) without any encryption using `port=9300`. So when I have my `config.ini` file as the following, it runs perfectly fine:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
LogonTimeout=10
ReconnectInterval=5
FileLogPath=./Logs/
FileStorePath=./Sessions
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=N
DataDictionary=fix/FIX44.xml
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
CheckLatency=N
PossResend=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ResetOnError=Y
MaxLatency=5
Account=[ACCOUNT NUMBER]
Username=[UUID]
SenderCompID=[USERNAME]
Password=[API PASSWORD]

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=OEC_TEST
HeartBtInt=30
EncryptMethod=0
SocketConnectHost=api.gainfutures.com
```

However, in order to use their encrypted system to set up a login system, I'll have to use `port=9400` which uses SSL. So I updated the `config.ini` file as below:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
LogonTimeout=10
ReconnectInterval=5
FileLogPath=./Logs/
FileStorePath=./Sessions
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=N
DataDictionary=fix/FIX44.xml
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
CheckLatency=N
PossResend=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ResetOnError=Y
MaxLatency=5
Account=[ACCOUNT NUMBER]
Username=[UUID]
SenderCompID=[USERNAME]
Password=[API PASSWORD]    

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=OEC_TEST
HeartBtInt=30
EncryptMethod=0
SocketConnectHost=api.gainfutures.com
SocketConnectPort=9400
SSLEnable=Y
SSLValidateCertificates=N
SSLCheckCertificateRevocation=N
```

I have not been able to connect to the server at all and I keep getting an `"onLogout received from server"` message immediately after sending a Login request. I have a function that's supposed to print out heartbeats if it was successful (like it does for non-encrypted port). But For this one, it does nothing.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have a mismatch in the definitions. They are using some other settings that you're not aligned to. I would start by checking the timeout, the reset variables and the dictionary. These are (from my experience) the usual suspects.

Comment: Don't you need to specify a certificate somewhere?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov I've tried changing the time variable and reset variables - it didn't make any difference. I have not used a data dictionary before or in this project. Where do they usually reside? Also, Gain Futures have mentioned the following in terms of  9400: `Test Environment: api.gainfutures.com - over SSL, target host - gainfutures.com`. Where should I use the `target host` here? [Here](https://gainfutures.com/wp-content/uploads/FIX.pdf)'s their FIX api documentation

Comment: @ChristophJohn in their documentation I linked above, they say the certificate field is nor required, so I didn't use it. Also, they did not provide any certificate info for test environment.

Comment: What is in the FIX message log?  I suspect you are seeing a `35=A` logon message immediately followed by a `35=5` logout message.  That would mean that you ARE connecting, but they don't like what they see your login message (e.g. bad user/pass, missing SenderSubID, etc).  Basically, you're phoning them and they answer, but then they hang up because they didn't like your "hello".

Comment: Also, I guarantee that your `UseDataDictionary=N` is a mistake.  Should be `=Y`.  But that's a whole separate issue, and not the cause of your current problem.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I'm seeing a `35=A` but there is no incoming message. My log shows the following: `06/04/2020 07:41:23 AM Sending Admin message to server. Session: FIX.4.4:<OEC USER>->OEC_TEST. Message: 8=FIX.4.49=13835=A34=149=<OEC USER>52=20200604-13:41:23.00056=OEC_TEST554=<PW>12003=<UUID>98=0108=30141=Y10=114

06/04/2020 07:41:23 AM onLogout received from server. Session: FIX.4.4:CRamasamy4419->OEC_TEST`

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier if connected successfully (through non-encrypted), the log says this: `06/04/2020 07:53:16 AM Received Admin message from server. Session: FIX.4.4:<OEC USER>->OEC_TEST. Message: 8=FIX.4.49=59135=A34=149=OEC_TEST52=20200604-13:53:1656=<OEC USER>98=0108=3012004=<BIG string>` Also, if I say `DataDictionary=Y`, I get the following log error: `06/04/2020 07:46:06 AM Configuration failed: fix/FIX44.xml: Could not parse data dictionary file`.

Comment: That's not a message log (the message log has only FIX messages in it and it's the most valuable thing you'll need for debugging problems), but your conclusion is correct.  And the DD error means it can't find your DD file.  Try using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

It's clear that something in your SSL config is wrong, but this is not something I'm very good at.  Hopefully someone else can step up.  Try the quickfix mailing list?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier after adding a `fix/FIX44.xml` file for DD, I don't see the parsing error anymore. It didn't solve the problem though. This is what I see in my message log: `20200604-14:14:31.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.49=13835=A34=149=<OEC USER NAME>52=20200604-14:14:31.00056=OEC_TEST554=<OEC PASSWORD>12003=<UUID>98=0108=30141=Y10=114
`

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I see the following in the events log: `20200604-14:14:31.000000000 : Connecting to api.gainfutures.com on port 9400 (Source :0)
20200604-14:14:31.000000000 : Initiated logon request
20200604-14:14:31.000000000 : Socket Error: Connection reset by peer.
20200604-14:14:31.000000000 : Disconnecting`

Comment: Yes, as I said, the DD is a side issue.  Your issue is probably SSL-config related.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov , Gain Futures forum support asked me to use stunnel or similar solution. I'm not familiar using them for SSL and quickfix. Do you have any recommended reading/example?